# How to bind input type='date' with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind

so I am trying to bind value for input of type date..

Here is my AngularJS code that I am trying to bind the value to:

```
$scope.date = new Date();
$scope.dateString = dateFilter($scope.date,'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

And html:

```
<input class="date" type="date" ng-bind="dateString">
```

What I am trying to do, is I am trying to set default value to todays date. However, when I am loading my page, it just gives me following result:

```
<input class="date ng-binding" type="date" ng-bind="dateString">08-04-2015</input>
```

Any help will be more than welcome :)

Thanks,
uksz

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: you need to be using version 1.3 or higher for date support. you also want to use ng-model instead of ng-bind, because ng-bind is one way only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using version 1.3 or higher for date support. you also want to use ng-model instead of ng-bind, because ng-bind is one way only

Comment: Thanks so much! Turns out I am using 1.2.26.

Comment: Is updating version pretty straight forward? Or I need to take a look at keynotes, to change my code :)?

Comment: Ok, so most likely I wont be able to update to 1.3 as ionic framework doesnt support it yet. Is there any way i can go around this problem?

Comment: are you using bootstrap, there are a selection a date picker directives that you can use. If you are using bootstrap, then this: https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Actually, dependencies you will need are:
AngularJS 1.2.26 or higher (1.0.x will not work)
moment.js 2.8.3 or higher for date parsing and formatting
bootstrap's glyphicons for arrows (Can be overridden in css)